# How can I run npm task after an ongoing task in the same terminal

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, protractor

I have two tasks that I would like to run one after the other, the first task is ongoing and I need to wait until is complete:

```
{
    "serve": "node_modules/.bin/ng serve",
    "flake": "node_modules/.bin/protractor-flake --parser standard  --max-attempts=3 -- e2e/protractor.conf.js"
}
```

`serve` task is ongoing and I want to wait until it's ready and run "flake". 
Basically I'm trying to to run Angular e2e tests with `Protractor-flake` on CI boxes. e2e needs application to run.

I tried `concurrently` but it doesn't wait for `ng server` to be ready.
I tried also this:

```
concurrently \"ng serve\" \"wait-on http://localhost:8000/ && npm run flake\" --kill-others
```

But it didn't run the tests.

Comment: I've done this before by mixing concurrently and wait-on, e.g. https://github.com/textbook/cyf-library/blob/master/package.json#L29. @trichetriche please read the question; the point is they want to run them in parallel, but have the second wait for the first one to be "ready".

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the comment, I'm looking into your code - so where do you do `serve`?

Comment: That's via https://github.com/textbook/cyf-library/blob/master/package.json#L28, `yarn start` builds the client in prod mode then copies over the files and starts the server. `e2e:ci` is the entry point for the CI script, see https://github.com/textbook/cyf-library/blob/master/.travis.yml#L19.

Comment: Firstly I think `wait-on` requires a specific "protocol", e.g. the `http-get://` I'm using. Secondly, have you added any logging to find out what's going on? E.g. for `wait-on` you can set `-l` for logging and `-v` for verbose.

Comment: I have `http` protocol : The specified command ("bla:ci:safe") is invalid. For a list of available options. I do have -v but not much verbose. I'm on windows by the way.

Comment: Oh I found my mistake! i have ng instead of npm run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174266/discussion-between-shiva-and-jonrsharpe).